# IIB - convert BLOB to String using Java Compute Node

Tags: java, messagebroker

So I have a simple message flow with a File Read node, parsing a .txt (saying whatever) to BLOB, which I have to convert to a string in a Java Compute Node. Never used JAVA, how do I go about this?

Then I have to give the string a new value (whatever) and switch the logical tree body element to the new value.

Should be simple, but still a steep learning curve for me, out of nowhere. All helps are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

When parsing to BLOB, you end up with a byte array in `assembly.getMessage().getRootElement().getLastChild().getLastChild()`, and converting that to String should be easy:

```
String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
```

You can get the charset from the Preperties subtree.

You can read about accessing the message tree parts here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac30330_.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, one other way to do it would be to parse the input file with a dedicated parser directly (DFDL, ...). If one day your document is not in the format you expected, it will throw a proper error and won't crash on the java line trying to cast as a string something that is not a string. It might be too complex for your case (and also useless), but if you are learning, I would recommand you to play with the parsers so you won't have to learn about it for futur cases.

But reading as a BLOB is totally fine as long as you keep in minds that it means litteraly anything could be read, so the java solution is totally fine as long as you handle it properly (try/catch/throw).